# An injection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}^n$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I'm currently attempting to prove $\mathbb{N}^n \sim \mathbb{N}$ via [Cantor-Schroeder-Berstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Bernstein%E2%80%93Schroeder_theorem) (because I found no other way). In my work so far I've managed to find an injective function $f$ from $\mathbb{N}^n$ to $\mathbb{N}$ where $(a_1, \cdots, a_n) \mapsto 2^{a_1}3^{a_3}\cdots\rho_n^{a_n}$ where $\rho_n$ is the n-th prime number. I believe this function $f$ to be injective thanks to the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic). But I can't seem to find an injective function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}^n$.

Resuming, I have three questions:

1. Are my workings on $f$ correct?, that is, is $f$ really an injection?
2. Do you have any hints on finding an injective function $g$ from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}^n$?
3. Is there another, easier way of proving $\mathbb{N}^n \sim \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: You've already done the "hard" direction. There are some *very* simple and natural injections $\mathbb N \to \mathbb N^n$, or in more generality $X \to X^n$ for any non-empty set $X$...

Comment: An injective function from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N^n$ : why not $f(n) = (n, 0, 0, \ldots, 0)$ ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA THAT'S BRILLIANT.

Comment: another is $a\mapsto (a,a,a\cdots)$

Comment: If you use the convention that $0\not\in\mathbb{N}$, then just use $1$'s instead.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs: If you use the convention that $0\notin\Bbb N$ then you're wrong! $\stackrel{\smallsetminus.\circ}{\large\smile}$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA And, also, Isn't the function $f(n)=(n,0,\dots,0)$ a bijection?

Comment: @Miguelgondu, not at all. The point $(0,1,0,\ldots,0)$ is not in its range.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Oh, yes. I wasn't thinking correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. The function $g(k)=(k,0,\ldots,0)$ should work. There are many injections from $\mathbb{N}$ in to the much larger, more spacious $\mathbb{N}^n$.
3. Once you know that $\mathbb{N}\sim\mathbb{N}^2$, you could work by induction.

Comment: Is $\mathbb N^n$ really much larger and more spacious than $\mathbb N$?

Comment: Not if $n=1$. :P  Otherwise, it depends how you think of it. Cardinality-wise, obviously not. However, $\mathbb{N}^n$ is the first hyper-quadrant of $\mathbb{Z}^n$, which is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module of higher rank than $\mathbb{Z}$. I guess if a mathematical object contains a copy of another one, with all of its structure, and then adds more structure, I think of it as roomier, yeah. Is that fair?

Answer (score 2):

There are many other and better ways, look for the equivalence of $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ there is nice argument on the square.

Also one can just define such a map

$$(n,m) \mapsto \frac{(n+m)(n+m+1)}{2}+m$$